# Code::Blocks not compiling release for SFML project

Tags: c++, gcc, release, codeblocks, sfml

Whenever I try to build a release .exe for any SFML project, I get this message:

> ```
> -------------- Build: Release in SFMLPROJECT (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ---------------
>
> mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\SFML-2.1\lib -o bin\Release\SFMLPROJECT.exe obj\Release\main.o  
> -s  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -mwindows
>
> Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> 0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
> ```

And when I go to check on the Release folder, It's empty. If I try to run the project from Code Blocks, it "builds" like about, says this:

> ```
> -------------- Run: Release in SFMLPROJECT (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ---------------
>
> Checking for existence: C:\User\Desktop\C++\SFMLPROJECT\bin\Release\SFMLPROJECT.exe
> ```

...and then says: "It seems that this project has not been built yet. Do you want to build it now?". If I hit "yes", it just "builds" again without actually building anything. If I click "no" it just says the execution failed, and cancel of course does nothing.

I've tried looking for a solution but I just haven't come across any. I also tried using another compiler (Digital Mars) and I still encounter the same problem. Everything runs fine with Debug. Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen a few guys who couldn't even get their first project running with Code::Blocks, so I strongly recommend you to throw it away and switch to Visual C++.  Because I assume your final goal is not to become an expert of C++ compiler and software development toolkits, but to present your creativity to the world through your product.  (Maybe you can even throw away C++ in favor of Unity but I'm not an expert of it.)

If you are committed to using Code::Blocks, these articles might help:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqjNOd1UYtE
- http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=11652.0

(I recommend you to read them because of my general knowledge on trickiness of using MingW)

Comment: I think you might be right about Code::Blocks. That said, I'm definitely going to check out your links because I'm pretty used to the set-up already. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that telling people to use another IDE does help them much at all. Especially when so many people recommend Code::Blocks to C++ newbies.
That said, I recommend using Visual Studio even when there is no (official) SFML2.1 for VS2013.